# net.msmq not recognised for a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

Getting the following error when attempting to start a Windows service hosting a WCF service:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.msmq for the endpoint with binding NetMsmqBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Works fine if I remove the netmsmq binding and use the basichttp binding. Config is as below:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ManageContactService.ManageContact" behaviorConfiguration="ContactServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/ManageContact/ContactService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="net.msmq//localhost/private/testqueue" binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="MyMsmqBinding" contract="ManageContactService.IManageContact" />

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MyMsmqBinding">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ContactServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a colon:

net.msmq://localhost/private/testqueue